# Preventing Inheritance issues with coffeescript and gulp

Tags: inheritance, coffeescript, gulp

I frequently work by building out classes in coffeescript, each classing being its own coffeescript file. I then have a compiler (like Gulp) combine and minify all of the different class files I've built into a single minified .js file.

My problem comes from inheritance. Since my compiler is just tossing in the files without any particular order, I may end up the code below.

```
#file: otherThing.coffee
#the class "Thing" is not yet defined, this will error
class window.otherThing extends window.Thing  
    _prop: "that other thing"
    method: () => 
       super()

#file: thing.coffee
class window.Thing
    _prop: "the thing"
    method: () =>
       console.log(@_prop)
```

My current (sloppy) solution to this is to provide a comment in to each of these files like this.

```
#[COMPILE_PRIORITY:0.1]
```

I have the compiler sniff these tags out and order the files accordingly when concatenating them into a single file.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to make a dependency graph and then do a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). This kind of sort will build out an order for you based on that dependency graph, which you would build out based on the classes that are being extended.

Good news is that it seems like someone has already done this for CoffeeScript with [Coffee-Graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coffee-graph). So you could try putting a step in your Gulp file for Coffee-Graph which will send the files to the CoffeeScript compiler in (hopefully) the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

**Full disclosure**:

I have never used coffee script. However, I do use javascript and gulp  a LOT. As @Git Wizard [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37032030/4775223), maybe Coffee-Graph does the trick. However, there may be another way.

**What we know**

From [The Little Book on CoffeeScript](https://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html)

> Behind the scenes, CoffeeScript is using **JavaScript's native prototype**
>   to create classes; adding a bit of syntactic sugar for static property
>   inheritance and context persistence. As a developer all that's exposed
>   to you is the class keyword.

Javascript objects know about each other as long as they have been included or referenced by the same app, meaning as long as they are in the same *lexical context*. Since gulp is bringing all the files into the pipe your *coffee script compiler* may be compiling them as they come through the pipe stream one at a time. This surely seems to be the case, and hence missing the definitions for classes that are contained in other files.

From http://coffeescript.org/

> **Lexical Scoping and Variable Safety**
>
> The CoffeeScript compiler takes care to make sure that all of your
>   variables are properly *declared within lexical scope*.

**What we can try**

Use something like [gulp-concat](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat) to concatenate all your script files into a single file. Because the compiler has all the content all at once and hence all the classes are within the same *lexical scope* then it may be able to properly reference the all the defined classes.